# mail not sent from command line and php function

Tags: php, shell, email

I installed "mailutils" package in both servers, in the first server the mail is sent using command line, the second server the mail is not sent:

**dpkg --get-selections for first server:**

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep mail
heirloom-mailx                                  install
libmail-sendmail-perl                           install
libmailtools-perl                               install
libmailutils2                                   install
libreoffice-emailmerge                          install
mailutils                                       install
procmail                                        install
sendmail-base                                   install
sendmail-bin                                    install
sendmail-cf                                     install
```

**dpkg --get-selections for second server:**

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep mail
libmailutils2                                   install
libreoffice-emailmerge                          install
mailutils                                       install
```

The command line is:

```
echo -e "File mp4 is finished on Thank you for using this script" 2>&1 | sed '1!b;s/^/To: MYID@gmail.com\nSubject: File coding is done\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```

And this is the php function:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$send = mail('MYID@gmail.com', 'sujet', 'salut');

if($send) {
echo 'mail sent';
}
else
{
echo 'oho';
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: I will add a mail function later on

Answer (score 0):

Can your server send email if you call sendmail directly?

```
echo -e "File mp4 is finished on Thank you for using this script" 2>&1 | sed '1!b;s/^/To: MYID@gmail.com\nSubject: File coding is done\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```

Comment: The first server YES, the second one NO

Comment: I usually find setting up sendmail troublesome and is easy for mails sending out from your IP get marked as spam. For production applications, I use mail sending gateways like Mandrill / SendGrid (they do have free plans) which ensures my email get delivered and won't get marked as spam. It also require less setup in the server as these are just a few RESTful API calls.

Comment: I am just using mailutils before install postfix

Comment: Well, I installed postfix, now via command like it works, but via php mail function I am not receiving any mail, I edited my code above